# Search all columns on DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, search

I'm trying to get a search box to search more than one column on a datagrid. Currently this is what I've got:

```
Private Sub txt_search_TextChanged(sender As System.Object,
                              e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Me.CriticalBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'",
      Database29DataSet.Critical.AddressColumn, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

This works perfectly to search for 1 column (in this case AddressColumn) but I'm struggling to make it search for more than one column. I tried using a simple if statement and did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try multiple OR statements if you have a fixed number of columns

eg:

```
 Me.CriticalBindingSource.Filter = String.Format(
 "{0} LIKE '{1}%' OR {2} LIKE '{1}%'",
   Database29DataSet.Critical.AddressColumn,
   TextBox1.Text,
   Database29DataSet.Critical.Column2)
```